# Rails 3 nested routes question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I need some help with routes.  Here are my current routes.

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :create, :destroy] do
  resources :links, :only => [:create, :destroy], :shallow => true, :on => :member
end
```

and when I run rake routes I get this

```
  root               /(.:format)                     {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
  user_links  POST   /users/:user_id/links(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"links"}
  link        DELETE /links/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"links"}
  users       GET    /users(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
              POST   /users(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
  user        GET    /users/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

but I am trying to get my routes be this, which is what I had but I can't remember how I got it to work.  :(

```
  root                /(.:format)                     {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
  user_links   POST   /users/:user_id/links(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/links"}
  link         DELETE /links/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/links"}
  users        GET    /users(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
               POST   /users(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
  user         GET    /users/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Edit:

I guess the above doesn't really say much.  The differences in the routes is this.

```
  user_links  POST   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"links"} 
  link        DELETE {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"links"}  


  user_links  POST   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/links"}
  link        DELETE {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/links"}
```

Maybe this will help a bit.

Comment: I don't see the difference in the routes? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I want the links resources to use be able to use the user and links controller.  `{:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/links"}` and `{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/links"}` versus `{:action=>"create", :controller=>"links"}` and `{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"links"}`

Comment: see the answer to the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11849385/317884

Answer (score 1):

Try this first, delete any options in routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :links, :module => 'users'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still results with the same routes.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the   :shallow => true ... and you should see users/links

see also

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes

Comment: Thanks, I think that is the site where I got the idea from in the first place.  I tried removing it but I still got `:controller => "links" `  I must be missing something else.