# Rails 3 routes for nested controllers and sub-folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need some help with routes for nested controllers. I can't figure out from the Rails guide docs by myself.
I have the following controllers in a rails 3.2 app:

```
/app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb (class OrganizationsController)
/app/controllers/organization/events_controller.rb (class Organization::EventsController)
```

then, in routes.rb

```
resources :organizations, path: 'org' do
  resources :events
    member do
      get 'confirm'
    end
  end
end
```

running `rake routes` shows (only the relevant part for my issue):

```
 organization_event  GET  /org/:organization_id/events/:id(.:format)  events#show
```

The URL is ok, the route name is also ok, but the mapping to the "controller/action" is not right. Not as I want it to be. It should be `organization/events#show`.

What am I missing? How can I point this route to the correct controller. I chose to put the `events_controller` in the `organization` folder, because I already have another `events_controller` placed in the root of the controllers folder, and they have different purposes.
Thank you

Comment: I just realized there's another similar question, but still unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225248/rails-3-nested-routes-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
namespace :organization do
   resources :events 
      member do
        get "confirm"
      end
   end
end
```

More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

*EDIT*

Sorry, didn't understand you correctly.

```
resources :organizations, path: 'org' do
  resources :events, :module => "organization"
    member do
      get 'confirm'
    end
  end
end
```

Does that fit your needs?

Comment: I tried something similar, but I need the :organization_id in the route. The namespace solution indeed maps the correct controller (`organization/events`) but generates the route `/organization/events/:id`